# Why varchar size affects query performance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that generates a JSON string. It looks something like this, where `@Names` is `varchar(max)`:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(MAX) 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
create table #temp
(
    col1 varchar(100),
    col2 varchar(100),
    col3 varchar(100),
    col4 varchar(100),
    col5 varchar(100)
)

declare @count int = 1

WHILE @count <= 600
BEGIN
    insert into #temp select 'stuff', 'more stuff', 'even more stuff', 'not enough stuff', 'just the right stuff'
    select @count = @count + 1
END


;with cte as
(
    select Col1, Col2,col3, col4, col5 from #temp
)
select @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + '{"type": "Feature", ' +
'"properties": {' +
'"Name": "' + cte.Col1 + '",' + 
'"Category": "' + cte.Col2 + '",' + 
'"UserId": "' + cte.col3 + '",' + 
'"Other": "' + cte.col4 + '",' + 
'"lat": ' + cte.col5 + ',' + 
'"long": ' + cte.col5 + ',' + 
'"MyDate": "' + cte.col5 + '",' + 
'"Icon": "' + 'icons/MyIcon.svg' + '"' + 
'}' +
',"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates": [' + cte.col1 + ', ' + cte.col1 + ']}}'
from cte

declare @header varchar(500)
select @header = 
'{ ' +
'"type": "FeatureCollection", ' +
'"features": [ '

declare @footer varchar(100) = '] ' +
'} '
select @header + @Names + @footer as 'json'
```

The complete query takes about 15 seconds to run, while the query within the `cte` takes less than one second. The problem was with building the string outside the `cte`.

I ended up changing `@Names` to `varchar(5000)`, and the performance dramatically improved from 11 seconds to less than a second.

Why would this size change in `@Names` have such an improvement in the query? The `cte` query returns 600 rows.

Comment: You'd need to look at the actual execution plans, and STATISTICS IO and STATISTICS TIME to understand the difference.  The CTE might have a completely different plan when executed alone.  And one obvious problem is the Date predicate is not SARGable.  But it could be a problem with memory grants  for the query too.

Comment: It's impossible to answer without the schema or execution plans. First of all, SQL Server 2008 is out of support. Upgrading it is long overdue. Second, you should generate JSON in the client, not the query. Using `varchar` for coordinates exposes you to conversion errors. Finally, `Year(Date)` means you can't use any indexes on `Date`

Comment: I've edited the code and removed any dates. I _should_ generate the JSON in the client, but that's not what the client asked for, so it's a non-issue.

Comment: This should really be NVARCHAR. I doubt you can trust the json will remain free of unicode.

Comment: Internally, varchar(n) and varchar(max) are handled differently. varchar(max) can accommodate up to 2GB of data, so normal string handling operations are handled differently than a string that is limited in size to something so much smaller.